# How do I import data from serial monitor to excel document without copying and pasting?

Tags: arduino-mega, serial-data

I need to be able to import incoming data from a motion sensor and then from the serial monitor (where the data is) import the data to an excel document or file.

Any suggestions would help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Arduino IDE's serial monitor is just one of many tools that can open a serial port and collect information from it.

The first step is to make sure the data you are writing to the `Serial` object in the Arduino is in a format suitable for importing into Excel. Separate multiple values on one line with a comma `","` or tab `"\t"` character.

If you are running windows, you can often just use the built-in `type` command from a command prompt to write the serial port to a file:

```
type COM4 >> log.txt
```

(Assuming the Arduino is on COM4 and you want to write the data to a file called `log.txt`.)

If you're on a Mac, open the Terminal app and type:

```
screen -L /dev/tty.usbmodem1441335 9600
```

(Assuming your Arduino is on serial port named `tty.usbmodem1441335` and your port speed is 9600 bps.) The session will be written to a file called `screenlog.0`.

Then you can open the text/log file in Excel. If you rename it to end in `.csv`, that may also help Excel recognize it as tabular data.

Comment: You could even connect directly to the serial port, from within excel, using VBA. http://www.dailyfreecode.com/Forum/accessing-serial-port-excel-vba-26041.aspx