# How to save arduino serial monitor data into excel file

Tags: arduino-uno

I am looking for the software that can help me to save arduino serial monitor data into excel file. And how to use that with your own code.

Comment: copy and paste with a limited amount of data ... otherwise, write a script in Processing to read data from serial and write the data into a csv file .... http://processing.org

Comment: use csv file format

Comment: Look for a serial terminal software which supports logging to a text file.
There are simpler ones than PuTTy.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is able to access the serial data and export it to a text file, which can then be converted to an excel file within *Excel > Data > From Text*. However, the data should be formatted in a way that excel can read it by separating values with a delimiter such as `","`.

Once you have done this, simply run your serial data and open up your computer's console and write:
`type COM(# here) >> serialdata.txt`

Finally, import this text file into excel.

You could also use [Excel VBA with MSCOMM](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/Forum/accessing-serial-port-excel-vba-26041.aspx) to take the serial data directly into excel.

This answer is a regurgitation of a [duplicate question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/47805/how-do-i-import-data-from-serial-monitor-to-excel-document-without-copying-and-p) asked earlier.